# Aren't Rakshasas known for uncontrollable passions, lust, greed and deceit?

Tags: rakshasa

Aren't Rakshasas known for uncontrollable passions, lust, greed and deceit ?

Comment: Yes!!!!!!!!!!!!@@

Comment: Most of them, Yes. But there were great Rakshasa too who chose the path of devotion instead like Prahlada, Bali, Vibhishana etc.

Comment: Rakshasas are cannibals and called Giant Trolls in english, and are "someone who disturbs everyone". Asuras are humans but without Dharma.

Comment: Yes but its same attributes are manifested in Man also than its Rakshasas, now rakshasas are not external entity who needs to be destroyed by some Gods.. its our prospenity to do the mistakes is rakshasas, Rakshasas are human being exhibiting only those attribute